# difference between š and ö

Tags: python, numpy

Machine: windows 10
Python version: 3.5.0
Language settings: current language for non-Unicode programs is English (United States)

I have some data involving names saved in a csv file that is saved in ASCII but characters such as the two in the question title appear properly regardless whether I open it in excel, notepad, notepad++ etc. They also appear properly once loaded in the python environment (IDLE). But I have trouble saving them as output.

In particular, what I was doing without issues until I got problematic symbols in my data was:

```
with open(output, 'ab') as f:
    np.savetxt(..)
```

After various experimentations, it gets down to the following. This works:

```
>>> with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, np.array(['ö'])[:,None], fmt = '%s')
```

But this doesn't.

```
>>> with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, np.array(['š'])[:,None], fmt = '%s')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#265>", line 2, in <module>
    np.savetxt(f, np.array(['š'])[:,None], fmt = '%s')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1215, in savetxt
    fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\compat\py3k.py", line 35, in asbytes
    return str(s).encode('latin1')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u0161' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)
```

- What is the different between the two? Is it that the first is within a 256-units list but the second isn't (based on the error message).
- Is there a workaround for this that does not involve utf-8? I am asking based on the fact that `np.save('test', np.array(['š'])[:,None])` works without problems and my understanding is that it also works on a binary manner -correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, first one is, second isn't. It is trying to encode it in Latin-1 and there is no "š" character in Latin-1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

Why are you avoiding UTF-8 is the question :) in this time and age I don't see a reason.